# Как записать информацию переменной STRING в текстовый файл?

Tags: python

Необходимо записать данные переменной STRING в текстовый файл также как они выходят на PRINT.
КОД:

```
x = {"one": 1, "two": 2,"three": 3, "four": 4}

string = "\n".join([f"{key} = {value}" for key, value in x.items()])
print(string)

fname = 'ТЕСТ'

file = 'X:\\TELEGRAMM\\DATAPAY\\' + f'{fname}' + '.txt'

open(file, 'w')

file.write(string)
file.close()
```

РЕЗУЛЬТАТ:

```
one = 1
two = 2
three = 3
four = 4

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "X:\TELEGRAMM\musorka.py", line 19, in <module>
    file.write(string)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
open(file, 'w')
file.write(string)
file.close()
```

Вы открыли файл, но не сохранили никуда его "хэндл". И пытаетесь потом писать данные не в файл, а в строку с его названием.

В общем нужно сохранить хэндл файла в переменную и лучше использовать конструкцию `with`, чтобы не думать потом о закрытии файла, оно будет сделано автоматически:

```
with open(file, 'w') as f:
    f.write(string)
```